# How to trigger an upload dialog when clicking on image

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my index page I've got several images which represent photo albums. These images are the covers for each album.

I want a user to have the ability to change these cover images by just clicking onto them. So, by doing that a file dialog should pop up and the user can select the new cover image.

My approach so far was creating a partial with a very basic form which uploads the image and shows the file dialog when clicked.

```
_cover.html.erb

<%= form_for(album) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

For what is the link part I haven't been able to figure out how to trigger the file dialog. Something like this obviously doesn't work, but it should give an idea what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<%= link_to (image_tag album.image_url), render partial: 'cover', locals: {album: album}, action: :update_cover %>
```

Btw, I have been able to upload the new cover with that form using a simple upload button produced by the `render partial ...` part from my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after some research. For me the best solution was just sticking the image which I wanted as an upload trigger into a `<label>` tag.

```
<label>
    <input name="album[image]" id="album_image" type="file">
    <img src="path_to_image" alt="my_image" width="200" height="200">          
</label>
```

Really easy but from what I read there seems to be some IE < 11 problems with that, which I have not tested.